# How to concatenate integer with string

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying this

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(month,[patient_date_birth],getdate()) as varchar(10))+ 'month'
```

but not working !!
any help please

This is my select query

```
SELECT study_patient_name+' '+study_patient_prenom as Patient,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(month,patient_date_birth,getdate()) > 12 THEN DATEDIFF(year,patient_date_birth,getdate()) 
        ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(month,patient_date_birth,getdate()) as varchar )+ ' month' 
    END as Age 
from patient
```

Comment: Not working? Wrong result or an error?

Comment: This should work. What is the error message?

Comment: i get an error:Failed to convert the varchar value '11moi' to type int data.

Comment: So, what's in `patient_date_birth`? And [edit] all your comment answers into your question.

Comment: patient_date_birth is date of birthday

Comment: Just that you know, datediff does not return the months between the dates, but how many times the month has changed, so the datediff between 31st and 1st (next month) as 1 month

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(month,CAST([patient_date_birth] AS DATE),getdate()) as varchar(10))+ ' month'
```

Answer (score 0):

the error i made is i didn't cast the first part of case `CAST(DATEDIFF(year,patient_date_birth,getdate()) as varchar)`

Comment: Hard to tell if the above is a confirmation that the [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32735904/104223) worked OR is a different solution altogether.  If the previous answer worked, please mark it as the answer and leave a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead. Otherwise, can you elaborate on how you solved the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast both elements of the CASE statement to varchar so the result is always varchar regardless of whether 'month' appears in the result:

```
SELECT
'dave'+' '+'rave' as Patient,
'ENT' as Service,
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(month, '2015-02-25', getdate()) > 12 
    THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(year, '2015-02-25', getdate()) as varchar(10))
    ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(month, '2015-02-25', getdate()) as varchar(10)) + ' month' 
END as Age
```

Comment: SELECT
[study_patient_name]+' '+[study_patient_prenom] as Patient
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(month,[patient_date_birth],getdate()) > 12
THEN DATEDIFF(year,[patient_date_birth],getdate()) 
 
       ELSE CAST( DATEDIFF(month,[patient_date_birth],getdate() ) as varchar )+ ' month'
   END as Age
from patient ...but not working when trying to concatenate with month